# Add two integer fields and assign as default to another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So i have a model with three fields (A, B, C) I want C to have a default value of A+B.

Anyway i can use a callable value for default or maybe aggregation within models.py?

How do i do this?

Comment: This is a great candidate for a `pre_save` signal, or even the `save` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As karthkir said, this is the sort of thing you should be doing in the save method.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.C:
            self.C = self.A + self.B
        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Anyway we can do it dynamically? While user is inputing data it gets updated?

Comment: If you write some JavaScript, yes. Nothing to do with Django in any case.

Comment: Thanks, I think your suggestion would suffice for now. I'll get to the ui design after.